# Unterschied zwischen "in letzter Sekunde" und "in letzter Minute"

Tags: meaning, usage

Eine Sekunde ist eine kürzere Zeitspanne, aber empfinden Sprecher des Deutschen eine Rettung "in letzter Sekunde" tatsächlich als knapper als eine "in letzter Minute"? Oder sind die beiden Phrasen synonym?

Und warum wurden Menschen bis zur Jahrtausendwende überwiegend "in letzter Minute" gerettet, während Hilfe heute immer häufiger erst "in letzter Sekunde" zu kommen scheint?

[image: Ngram für "in letzter Stunde" und "in letzter Minute"]

*Bild-Quelle: [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20letzter%20Sekunde%2Cin%20letzter%20Minute&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20letzter%20Sekunde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20letzter%20Minute%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20letzter%20Sekunde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20letzter%20Minute%3B%2Cc0)*

Comment: @akuzminykh oder Substantivierung ("zum Übertriebenen") statt direktem Nomen ("zur Übertreibung"). Und sicherlich "Synonym" und "zugesp_itzt."

Comment: "Im letzten Moment / Augenblick" ist eine weitere Variante. Auch "in letzter Stunde" kommt gelegentlich vor, ist aber wahrscheinlich in unserer schnelllebigen Zeit nicht mehr dramatisch genug,

Answer (score 7):

Ich wäre vorsichtig mit diesen Daten. Google mag Zugriff auf viele Informationen bieten, aber ob eine ausreichend große Menge an Textproben vorhanden ist, um Schlüsse wie "bis zur Jahrtausendwende..." zu ziehen, müsste man belegen bevor man sich daranmacht, den Zahlen eine Bedeutung beizumessen. Da springen mir zunächst schonmal die Prozentangaben ins Auge: Worauf beziehen die sich denn? In der Datenbank vorhandene Texte? Welche? Bücher, Presseartikel, Gesprächstranskriptionen, ...?

Ansonsten sind beide Varianten synonym und beschreiben eine Rettung, bei der man gerade noch rechtzeitig eingegriffen hat. Während eine Sekunde durchaus knapper wahrgenommen wird als eine Minute, hängt die genaue Variante von der Präferenz des Sprechers/Hörers/Lesers oder eventuell noch von den Umständen ab. Persönlich würde ich "in letzter Sekunde" wählen, wenn kurz nach der Rettung ein Ereignis stattfindet, dessen Eintritt die Rettung unmöglich gemacht hätte. Beispiel: Jemand wird aus dem Fahrstuhl gerettet. Unmittelbar nachdem er die Kabine verlassen hat und in Sicherheit ist, stürzt sie in die Tiefe. Bei einer Rettung in letzter Minute wäre der Absturz der Kabine zwar unausweichlich oder sehr wahrscheinlich gewesen, ist aber nicht eingetreten. Das ist aber nur meine Meinung.

Falls der steile Anstieg zwischen ca. 2007 und 2020 kein bloßes Datenartefakt ist, beispielsweise ein vermehrtes Vorhandensein von Presseartikeln in der Datenbank, könnte man sich tatsächlich überlegen, dass sich in den letzten Jahren eine Tendenz zu etwas mehr Dramatik in den Texten zeigt. Aber um diesen Schluss zu ziehen, müssten mehr Informationen über die Daten vorliegen.

Comment: Der Hinweis auf die Unklarheit der Daten von Google allein macht diese Antwort in meinen Augen schon das +1 wert. Der Rest der Antwort ist aber auch nicht zu verachten. ;)

Comment: Schade, dass hier für eine Antwort gestimmt wird, die sich mit ihrer Ignoranz brüstet. Die Datengrundlage und die Darstellung werden auf der Webseite des Google Ngram Viewers und in einem Wikipedia-Artikel erläutert. Würdest du den Duden oder andere Quellen auf dieselbe Weise in Zweifel ziehen? Sicher nicht, obwohl du dort auch nicht weißt, wie die Informationen zustande kamen. Google dagegen ist hier transparent und die Daten sind öffentlich zugänglich. [contd.]

Comment: [contd.] Normalisiert man die Daten – wie von [Younes & Reips (2019)](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0213554) beschrieben – dann ergeben sich ganz ähnliche Verläufe, die dieselben Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Phrasen aufweisen.

Comment: @WilhelmGeselle Die zwei Fragen *sind die beiden Phrasen synonym?* und *warum wurden Menschen bis zur Jahrtausendwende überwiegend "in letzter Minute" gerettet, während Hilfe heute immer häufiger erst "in letzter Sekunde" zu kommen scheint?* werden doch klar beantwortet - unabhängig von der Kritik an der Google-Statistik. Und dass in german.stackexchange Antworten nicht Anspruch auf die absolute Wahrheit erheben, sondern eine Meinung vertreten, ist auch nicht ungewöhnlich.

Comment: *Schade, dass hier für eine Antwort gestimmt wird, die sich mit ihrer Ignoranz brüstet*
Schade, dass deine weiteren Erläuterungen zu den Daten (Suche in Worttripeln) verschwunden sind.

*Würdest du den Duden oder andere Quellen auf dieselbe Weise in Zweifel ziehen?*
Ich hinterfrage alle meine Quellen, das ist informationelle Sorgfaltspflicht. Dem Duden vertraue ich tendenziell mehr als dem Internet, da er ca. 100 Jahre länger Zeit hatte, die deutsche Sprache zu beschreiben. Ist aber eh müßig, da der Duden meines Wissens keine quantitativen Aussagen zur Häufigkeit von Redewendungen macht :)

Comment: @interlinguex "Ich hinterfrage alle meine Quellen, das ist informationelle Sorgfaltspflicht." Beautifully put. Couldn't agree more. Best advice ever. It keeps the brain going too. Downright love it!I And if you have to pray anyway, don't pray to Something, pray to Everything.

Comment: @PaulFrost  Meine Antworte entsprechen immer die absolute Wahrheit, meine Meinung nach. Die absolute Wahrheit entspricht aber nicht immer meine  Meinung und meine Antworte erst recht nicht. "Sie sind ein Sack" umschreibt Behälter. Frag der Duden.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: *Erstens meine Entschuldigung für meine schlechten Grammatik- und Rechtschreibkentnisse. Der Grund, weshalb ich mich dennoch traue, diese Frage zu beantworten, ist, dass sie in allen Sprachen gleich ist.*

*Der Unterschied zwischen "in letzter Stunde", "in letzter Minute" und "in letzter Sekunde" liegt darin, was in diesen Zeitspannen getan werden kann. Sie sind somit nicht synonym oder austauschbar.*

**In der letzte Stunde ist die Arbeit am schwersten.**
sagt was aus über den letzten Teil einer längeren Zeitspanne.
Keine Eile da.

**In der letzte Minute kriegt man es doch noch geschafft.**
erklärt, wie knapp die Zeit ist im Bezug zum Zeitbedarf.
Das hat alles mit Eile zu tun.

**In letschter Sekund' entwischt man 'nem Unfall. Hajo?**
besagt, wie entscheidend diese eine Sekunde ist.
Eile ist dabei gar nicht länger relevant.
Es geht um Timing.

Edit: *Zu sagen, dass, wenn einem die Vorfahrt genommen wird im Straßenverkehr, man in letzter Stunde noch einen Unfall zuvorkommen konnte, macht gar keinen Sinn.*
*Genau so wenig Sinn macht es zu sagen, man hätte in letzter Sekunde seine Klausur fertig gekriegt. Dramatisch ist es ohne Zweifel, aber realistisch auf keinen Fall.*

*In letzter Stunde kann man noch gehen, in letzter Minute muss man schon laufen und die letzte Sekunde erlaubt nur noch einen Sprung.*

(Did I mention I prefer answering in English?)

Comment: @adonda  The sense of the answer is to indicate there very clearly is a difference between these expressions, relating to what is feasible in each time span, Either a  contemplated series of actions, a quick response or one single move. Contrary to what other answers say, they are neither synonym nor interchangeable, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @adonda I was told German questions are to be answered in German. Is that wasted effort?

Comment: Amen to that :(

Comment: @a_donda So besser?

Comment: Was sagt man dann? To escape übersetzt als entweichen.

Comment: @a_donda You might want to appreciate that Berend apparently is no native speaker.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Ich schulde Dir was.

Comment: @Berend I've retracted the downvote after the edit. My remark was not because of the verb but because of the noun : 'entweichen (lassen) ... einen Unfall' > the accident escapes, 'entweichen ... einem Unfall' > escape from an accident. Dative was necessary. And I am aware that German is difficult :-)